# Uncaught exception Error in my ML code

Tags: sml

When I use the Emacs to run my SML codes to understand the errors I get an error message. No matter what my codes are, every time I try `SML/Process/start SML repl`
and then type `use "project name";`, I get this message:

```
use "New_Pro";
[Opening New_Pro]
[use failed: Io: OpenIn failed on "New_Pro", Win32TextPrimIO:openRd: failed]

uncaught exception Error
    raised at: .../compiler/TopLevel/interact/interact.sml:24.14-24.28
-
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: You should `use "<filename>";`, i.e. you're probably missing a `.sml`.

Comment: @stefan, you should post that as an answer, as it is most likely hes problem. I'm not running windows so can't reproduce the "Win32Tex..." error. On linux it says "... No such file or directory".

Comment: @Jesper, Stefan was right, I missed a .sml but there is another way,too. I can use C-c C-l to load my project.

Answer (score 1):

I can use `C-c C-l` to load my Project.